# сравнить все значения элемента списка

Tags: python

есть такой код:

```
  def func()
    while True:
            d = len(resultfromsteam['response']['trade_offers_sent'])
                for i in range(d):
                    tradestate = resultfromsteam["response"]['trade_offers_sent'][i]['trade_offer_state']
                    time.sleep(1)
                    if tradestate == 9:
                       print('123')
                    else:
                      func()
```

Я хочу, чтобы элемент по очереди проверялся.Если значение ключа с таким-то элементом будет равно 9,print('123')
когда я делаю так,как написано в коде, мне вылетает ошибка,типо слишком много ты вызвал функцию.

Comment: Непонятно, зачем вас здесь рекурсия.

Comment: присвойте хотя бы приблизительными значениями ваш дикт. и покажите ошибку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for value in resultfromsteam["response"]['trade_offers_sent']:
    if value['trade_offer_state'] == 9:
        print('123')
    continue
```

Comment: мне убрать for i in range(d):????

Comment: @artemso72 Да, `resultfromsteam["response"]['trade_offers_sent']` — это список (тип `list`), он поддерживает интерфейс итерирования. На каждой итерации переменная `value` примет соответствующее значение из списка.

Answer (score 0):

```
if any(i['trade_offer_state'] == 9 for i in resultfromsteam["response"]['trade_offers_sent']):
    print('123')
```

Comment: А можно сделать переменную со значением 9

Comment: С каким значением?

Comment: этот any можно как-то узнать?

Comment: Вы его и так узнаёте в условном выражении. Функция `any` возвращает `True`, если хоть один из её аргументов истинен. В данном случае `any` вернёт `True`, если один из элементов `resultfromsteam["response"]['trade_offers_sent']` по ключу `trade_offer_state` возвращает 9.